# iphone lock button and the running app

Tags: iphone, background, core-location

this may be a simple one, but I don't know the answer.....

For testing whether my location-based app receives updates in background, I usually run the app and then press the Home button to put the app in background.  However, I am curious whether pressing the Lock button (at the top) will put the app in background or not.

Regards.

Comment: This is trivial for you to test. Put an `NSLog` in your `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` handler is see if your message is logged when you hit the lock button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Hitting the lock button does background the application.  However when you unlock it, the application is then brought back to the foreground.  Should be able to test this within your App Delegate and simple log statements.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply!! :)

Comment: I just tried it, it does move to the background on screen lock.

Comment: +1, for answer on my ARC question lol I later found duplicate of it so I thought it's better to delete it but appreciating your effort here.